# Connection reset by peer (Python SMTP)

Tags: python, email, networking, server, smtp

Im new to the networking area. I am trying set up a simple email script and im running into some issues. I could be missing something completely obvious but I wouldnt know due to my knowledge on this subject. I have `MIME` in here currently due to some other testing i was doing, but for now i swapped over to `EmailMessage`. Any knowledge  would be very helpful. Thank you!

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib
```

```
smtp_server = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
inUsername = input('Enter your email: ')
inPassword = 'randomPassword'

subject = 'Test'
text = 'Hello this is a text from my computer'
sendingTo = ["randomEmail@email.com"]

message = EmailMessage()
message['From'] = inUsername
message['To'] = sendingTo
message['Subject'] = subject
message.set_content(text)

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 465) 
server.ehlo()
#server.starttls()
#server.ehlo()
server.login(inUsername, inPassword)

smtp.send_message(message)
#smtp.quit()
server.close()

print('Email has ideally been sent.')
```

Comment: If this is on a home/residential network, understand that ISPs block email service from home/residential networks.

Comment: I am using my home network for this, is there anyway around it?

Comment: E-mail is touchy due to all the spam, so ISPs and e-mail providers make it difficult. You may be able to use a hosting service to create a VM from which you could provide the e-mail service, but getting other e-mail providers to play with you will also present a problem. This is really not a programming problem, so you may need to ask about that on [su] or [sf].

Comment: ah okay, thank you for the information. do you know if i say bring my laptop into the office this would work since it isnt at residential  isp?

Comment: That would be up to how the office network is configured. You will need to ask the network administrators as they my have some rules configured to block it to prevent infected machines from sending spam from within the network, which is something common for network administrators to do. I have noticed that much of the spam I receive is now from hosting services like Microsoft Azure, etc.